# ¿Cómo borrar un elemento que aparece cada 8 elementos en una lista de cadenas en Python?

Tags: python-3.x, array

Suponga que usted tiene una lista de cadenas como la siguiente:

```
the_list = ['02:00', '  GBP', '', 'Construction Output (MoM) (Jan)', '1.1%', '0.5%', '2.0%', '',
            '02:00', '  GBP', '', 'U.K. Construction Output (YoY) (Jan)', '9.9%', '9.2%', '7.4%', '',
            '02:00', '  GBP', '', 'GDP (MoM)', '0.8%', '0.2%', '-0.2%', '',
            '02:00', '  GBP', '', 'GDP (YoY)', '10.0%', '9.3%', '6.0%', '',
            '02:00', '  GBP', '', 'Index of Services', '1.0%', ' ', '1.2%', '']
```

De la cual cada 8 elementos aparece uno que es `''`, siendo este una cadena vacía, y que a su vez es la misma cadena vacía que existe siguiente a aquellas llamadas   `GBP`

Cómo podría la variable `the_list` ser actualizada de tal forma que borre el elemento **que aparece cada 8 elementos** (`''`)?

Comment: Hola. Recuerda que las preguntas sin código, errores y pruebas no son bien recibidas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto se puede resolver en una sola línea, puedes generar una lista nueva omitiendo el elemento múltiplo de 8:

```
newList = [v for k, v in enumerate(the_list) if (k+1) % 8]
```

Lo que genera:

```
[
    '02:00', '  GBP', '', 'Construction Output (MoM) (Jan)', '1.1%', '0.5%', '2.0%', 
    '02:00', '  GBP', '', 'U.K. Construction Output (YoY) (Jan)', '9.9%', '9.2%', '7.4%',
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Una de las formas de eliminar elementos de una lista es usando el metodo pop.

En este caso ya se conoce el indice de los elementos a eliminar (cada 8 elementos). Por lo que se puede crear un loop, donde se elimine un elemento cada 8 elementos hasta que se llegue al tamaño de la lista.

Por ejemplo:

```
indice_elemento = 2 #Indicamos en indice el primer elemento a eliminar
while indice_elemento < len(the_list): #La operacion se repetira siempre que el indice a eliminar exista en la lista
    the_list.pop(indice_elemento) #Eliminamos el elemento de la lista
    indice_elemento += 7 #Se usa 7 por que se elimino un elemento
```

El resultado seria:

```
the_list
['02:00', '  GBP', 'Construction Output (MoM) (Jan)', '1.1%', '0.5%', '2.0%', '',
 '02:00', '  GBP', 'U.K. Construction Output (YoY) (Jan)', '9.9%', '9.2%', '7.4%', '',
 '02:00', '  GBP', 'GDP (MoM)', '0.8%', '0.2%', '-0.2%', '',
 '02:00', '  GBP', 'GDP (YoY)', '10.0%', '9.3%', '6.0%', '',
 '02:00', '  GBP', 'Index of Services', '1.0%', ' ', '1.2%', '']
```

Comment: Entonces, sí quisiera eliminar el elemento `8`, tendría que establecer `indice_elemento = 8` y luegodebajo de `the_list.pop(indice_elemento)` establecer `indice_elemento += 7`?